# Image png color css or html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, png

I have this [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/807/samplev.png/) in my website, is a png.I want to know if there is anyway with HTML5 , javascript or css to change the color of the image? At least the image change to white (invert color black to white, not the transparency).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your end goal, aside from changing the color? For example, why can't you use an image editor and upload the new image?

Comment: You need to provide more details. In additional to the other comment, which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: Well wanted to support all... but for now Firefox, Chrome will be nice. Latest versions , would be nice ... I guess with canvas HTML5 is possible.

Comment: Ken, just a simple example to change the image that is black to white, without using any image editor.

Comment: I think what you may want to do is create both versions of the image, then use an event like hover to change the src of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *cannot* do this in plain HTML or CSS. You *can* do this with JS/HTML Canvas, but there is probably a much easier and more compatible solution than JS/HTML Canvas for performing image manipulation.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may just want to create a second image that you swap out with the first. There are also some decent image manipulation packages in server-side languages like PHP, if you need to do something more dynamic.

If you are set on using js, the code below is modified from [your example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/).

Using your example:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        drawImage(this);
    };
    imageObj.src = "darth-vader.jpg";
};

function drawImage(imageObj){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var destX = 69; //update these to set the image position
    var destY = 50;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, destX, destY);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        if(data[i] == 0 && data[i+1] == 0 && data[i+2] ==0){ //if black, ie. red, green, and blue are all 0
            //switch to white
            data[i] = 255; //red
            data[i+1] = 255; //green
            data[i+2] = 255; //blue
        }
        // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
    }

    // overwrite original image
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. Image manipulation is possible through HTML5 Canvas, and although it may not be an easy task, changing the image's color IS possible.

Comment: Yep, I think is possible.. BraedenP has right, and javascript? I found this [example](http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/) ..but not sure .

Comment: I'm sure you can find a way with JS, but you can't do it with HTML or CSS. And the solution is probably simpler than using JS for image color manipulation.

Comment: Would like to use HTML5 Canvas , just would like an example. using just that image, when i change the background color to black i still have the same image , but in white.

Comment: Background color is for the background of html elements like div or td. It won't edit the colors in an image. Using HTML5 Canvas will require finding an existing library that can handle your needs.

Comment: In the example you posted, they are changing the color of the HTML element, not the image itself. As the article states: "Basically, I took a solid black PNG image and carved out the parts where I wanted the background to peek through. Then I applied the color animations to the background of the element containing this PNG frame. As a result the image appears to be changing color, pretty nifty right?"

Comment: Yep, nice ... but I just to change the image to white , probably using this [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/)

Can you get a JSFiddle example with my image? Thanks

Comment: i took the code from your example and modified it to switch all black pixels to white. let me know how that works out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, was something like that i was looking just implemented with some diferences

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained why you aren't just using Photoshop to do it, but I assume you have your reasons.

> Well wanted to support all... but for
>   now Firefox, Chrome will be nice.
>   Latest versions , would be nice ... I
>   guess with canvas HTML5 is possible.

I'm not sure how well it works with transparent `.png`s, but you could try [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/).

Here's a demo of the "Invert" effect: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/invert/

You've lucked out with the browser support for "Invert" - it works in even IE:

> Although a few of the effects in
>   Pixastic are simulated in IE with
>   proprietary filters, most actions and
>   effects will not work without a canvas
>   enabled browser. Please consider using
>   either Firefox, Opera or Safari

Comment: Yep that are good solutions ..but i just need a html5... without using any other program. Thanks for the help and ideas

Comment: @Ricardo Rodrigues: Why can't you use Pixastic? If you can use HTML5's canvas (which uses.. canvas and JavaScript), you can use Pixastic (which also uses.. canvas and JavaScript).

Comment: Want to use my own javascript , not other ;)

Comment: @Ricardo Rodrigues: Well, [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) is silly, but again, I assume you have your reasons. Here's a working jsFiddle of @Ken's answer: [http://jsfiddle.net/PeZJz/](http://jsfiddle.net/PeZJz/) - I [base64'd](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64) the image to avoid a security error because your image and jsFiddle do not share the same domain.